# DRF Reverse Not Finding Proper Route

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework and I cannot get reverse() to return the proper route for testing purposes. I must have made a mistake somewhere along the path of registering my routes but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

core/urls.py

```
class CoreRouter(DefaultRouter):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DefaultRouter, self).__init__()
        self.trailing_slash = '/?'

router = CoreRouter()
router.register(r'works', WorkViewSet, base_name='work')
router.registry.extend(fairs_exhibitions_router.registry)

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^api/(?P<version>(v1))/', include(router.urls)),
    re_path(r'^api/(?P<version>(v1))/', include('fairs_exhibitions.urls')),
]
```

fairs_exhibitions/urls.py:

```
router = CoreRouter()

router.register(r'fairs', FairTagViewSet, base_name='fair')
router.register(r'exhibitions', ExhibitionTagViewSet, base_name='exhibition')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

(I ommited includes/a couple of unrelated routes)

I can hit `api/v1/fairs` just fine but when i try to use `reverse()` i cant seem to find the fairs path:

`reverse(fairs)` or `reverse(fairs-list)` just says it's not found

The closest I got was `reverse('fair-list')` which yielded this error:

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'fair-list' with no arguments not found. 4 pattern(s) tried: ['api/(?P(v1))/fairs/?\.(?P[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'api/(?P(v1))/fairs/?$', 'api/(?P(v1))/fairs/?\.(?P[a-z0-9]+)/?$', 'api/(?P(v1))/fairs/?$']

It seems like my issue might have something to do with the `?$` but I cant figure out where that is coming from or how to handle it.

Comment: The kwarg should be `basename` instead of `base_name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kwargs` needed in the url ie. `version` needs to be given the reverse function.

```
reverse('fair-list', kwargs={'version':'v1'})
```

For more details visit [urls utility functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/)